# A way of calculating docker image's digest on local system

Tags: docker, docker-image

Dose anybody know how to calculate docker image's digest on local disk ?
I want to know where image's digest come from . I can calculate image-ID or layer-hash , but I can't find a way to find out image's digest . In fact what is exactly an image's digest ?
if it's a sha256 from image's content , so why I can't calculate it from extracted docker's image on local ?